# Is there a way of LOAD DATA INFILE (import) xlsx file into MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, excel, import, load

I know that this is discussed a lot but I don't find solution of how to do that.

What I need is to import an excel file (xls/xlsx) to my database table. It is a button which does that and the command which is executed is like that:

```
 string cmdText = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'importTest4MoreMore.csv' INTO TABLE management FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';";
```

It works great. But I need to import excel file not CSV. As far as I know LOAD DATA command does not support binary files which xls is. 
So what's the solution to that? Please help

Thanks a lot

*pepys*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.xls will never be importable directly into MySQL. it's a compound OLE file, which means its internal layout is not understandable by mere mortals (or even Bill Gates). .xlsx is basically just a .zip file which contains multiple .xml/xslt/etc. files. You can probably extract the relevant .xml that contains the actual spreadsheet data, but again - it's not likely to be in a format that's directly importable by MySQL's load infile.

The simplest solution is to export the .xls/xlsx to a .csv.

Answer (score 7):

How to import 'xlsx' file into MySQL:

1/ Open your '.xlsx' file Office Excel and click on 'Save As' button from menu and select

```
 'CSV (MS-DOS) (*.csv)'
```

from 'Save as type' list. Finally click 'Save' button.

2/ Copy or upload the .csv file into your installed MySQL server (a directory path like: '/root/someDirectory/' in Linux servers)

3/ Login to your database:

```
mysql -u root -pSomePassword
```

4/ Create and use destination database:

```
use db1
```

5/ Create a MySQL table in your destination database (e.g. 'db1') with columns like the ones of '.csv' file above.

6/ Execute the following command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/root/someDirectory/file1.csv' INTO TABLE `Table1` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Please note that the option 'IGNORE 1 LINES' says MySQL to ignore the first line of '.csv' file. So, it is just for '.xlsx' files with 1 header column. You can remove this option.

Comment: Works great except I had to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to get around a file permission error.

Answer (score 4):

You can load xls or xlsx files with [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool (MS Excel or MS Excel 2007 format) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). This tool opens Excel files directly, COM interface is not used; and command line is supported.

Comment: +1 Blatant plug, but on topic. Wonder how you managed to not use COM.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. So far I'm just saving as CSV file first. But the dbForge Studio for MySQL is not a solution to me since it has to be a implemented in my web application' code, so...

Comment: CSV format has no restrictions for data export and import, for other formats only first 50 rows are processed. Great Deal