# How to import xlsx file data by cell number in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a xlsx file where data is not categorized So i need to import a file and save all data into database . As in the below image there are two tables data.It's just a dummy data 
1) personal information 
2) other information
So I have to write a script where I can save all data into database tables. 
 [image]

Comment: And what's the problem? Have you looked at any of the PHP libraries for reading Excel files, like my [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Saw this one in the Related field to the right - worth reading. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982868/is-there-a-way-of-load-data-infile-import-xlsx-file-into-mysql-database-table?rq=1  You'll have to study the MySQL syntax for CREATE TABLE before importing the data though. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I looked at excel_reader php library and it's working fine but there is only one problem i.e It is replacing integer value with 'GENERAL' word and that value I'm getting in cellsInfo array inside raw.